# Substitute in sympy wihout evaluating or simplifying the expression

Tags: python, latex, sympy

Consider the follwing example:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
f = sqrt(3*x + 2)
```

Now I want to substitute a number, say `5` for `x` and get a LaTeX represenation, in this case it should return

`\\sqrt(3\\cdot 5 + 2)`

How can I do this?

I tried `latex(f.subs(x,2,evaluate=False))` but this results just in `\\sqrt(17)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [UnevaluatedExpr(5)](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#prevent-expression-evaluation) instead of 5:

```
>>> latex(f.subs(x, UnevaluatedExpr(5)))
'\\sqrt{2 + 3 \\cdot 5}'
```

This wrapper prevents the expression inside of it ("5") from interacting with the outside terms. Reference: [Prevent expression evaluation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#prevent-expression-evaluation)

---

The order of addends isn't the same after substitution, as `3*x + 2` and `3*5 + 2` get sorted differently by the printer. To avoid this, one can use `order='none'` which keeps whatever internal order the arguments have, without trying to put them in a human-friendly arrangement.

```
>>> latex(f, order='none')
'\\sqrt{2 + 3 x}'
>>> latex(f.subs(x, UnevaluatedExpr(5)), order='none')
'\\sqrt{2 + 3 \\cdot 5}'
```