# What is the best way to display numeric and symbolic expressions in python?

Tags: python, sympy

I need to produce calculation reports that detail step by step calculations, showing the formulas that are used and then showing how the results are achieved.

I have looked at using sympy to display symbolic equations. The problem is that a sympy symbol is stored as a variable, and therefore I cannot also store the numerical value of that symbol.

For example, for the formula σ=My/I , I need to show the value of each symbol, then the symbolic formula, then the formula with values substituted in, and finally the resolution of the formula.

---

M=100

y= 25

I=5

σ=My/I

σ=100*25/5

σ=5000

---

I’m new to programming and this is something I’m struggling with. I’ve thought of perhaps building my own class but not sure how to make the distinction the different forms. In the example above, σ is at one point a numerical value, one half of an symbolic expression, and also one half of a numerical expression.

Comment: It seems that you want a straightforward symbol table: a data structure with the symbol's string as the key, and other information (value, dependencies, etc.) in the columns.  Your question seems to ask for tutorial help in design and implementation; these are too broad -- off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following helps. This produces more or less what you want. You cannot get your fifth line of workings easily as you'll see in the code.

```py
from sympy import *

# define all variables needed
# trying to keep things clear that symbols are different from their numeric values
M_label, y_label, l_label = ("M", "y", "l")
M_symbol, y_symbol, l_symbol = symbols(f"{M_label} {y_label} {l_label}", real=True)
M_value, y_value, l_value = (100, 25, 5)
# define the dictionary whose keys are string names
# and whose values are a tuple of symbols and numerical values
symbols_values = {M_label: (M_symbol, M_value),
                  y_label: (y_symbol, y_value),
                  l_label: (l_symbol, l_value)}

for name, symbol_value in symbols_values.items():
    print(f"{name} = {symbol_value[1]}")  # an f-string or formatted string

sigma = M_symbol * y_symbol / l_symbol
print(f"sigma = {sigma}")

# option 1
# changes `/5` to 5**(-1) since this is exactly how sympy views division
# credit for UnevaluatedExpr
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842196/substitute-in-sympy-wihout-evaluating-or-simplifying-the-expression
sigma_substituted = sigma\
    .subs(M_symbol, UnevaluatedExpr(M_value))\
    .subs(y_symbol, UnevaluatedExpr(y_value))\
    .subs(l_symbol, UnevaluatedExpr(l_value))
print(f"sigma = {sigma_substituted}")

# option 2
# using string substitution
# note this could replace words like `log`, `cos` or `exp` to something completely different
# this is why it is unadvised. The code above is far better for that purpose
sigma_substituted = str(sigma)\
    .replace(M_label, str(M_value))\
    .replace(y_label, str(y_value))\
    .replace(l_label, str(l_value))
print(f"sigma = {sigma_substituted}")

sigma_simplified = sigma\
    .subs(M_symbol, M_value)\
    .subs(y_symbol, y_value)\
    .subs(l_symbol, l_value)
print(f"sigma = {sigma_simplified}")
```

Also note that if you wanted to change the `symbols_values` dictionary to keys being the symbols and values being the numerical values, you will have a hard time or seemingly buggy experience using the keys. That is because if you have `x1 = Symbol("x")` and `x2 = Symbol("x")`, SymPy sometimes treats the above as 2 completely different variables even though they are defined the same way. It is far easier to use strings as keys.

If you begin to use more variables and choose to work this way, I suggest using lists and for loops instead of writing the same code over and over.